# Is it possbile central banks are outside of books getting money from deflation?

Tags: currency, central-banking, deflation

Is it possile that central banks are secretly stealing from the economy by printing money when the the dollar deflates, so the dollar stay the same value and nobody notice it?

What if the dollar should have had massive deflations on graphs, but it didnt because the value was stolen by printing?

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of the recent attempts at monetary expansion ("printing money") has been to prevent deflation. There's nothing secret about it, and it doesn't "steal from the economy".

Comment: Not talking deflation vs inflation. Im saying the dollar should be constantly rising in value, benefiting the savers, but instead is going down artificially by printing, and the printed money is going to the government. This allows the government to mantain a stable dollar, avoiding riots, and still get money or value from the people. This clearly characterize a wealth transfer from the savers and salaries to the government without nobody noticing it.

Comment: That is just what inflation and deflation are. Your question is just the same question as "what's the optimal level of inflation?"